# how to prevent user from accessing other account's email when assigned under same application with same secret key in AZURE Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm new to this.
I have registered an app called **Oauth Test** for email authentication.
Then created a secret key to access the app.
I assigned this app to two users.

Now user A is using secret key and his own email id to access the mailbox.
User B is again using secret key and his own email id to access the mailbox. Its working fine for both the users.
The problem is if user A uses secret key with user B's email id, he is able to read B's emails. I want to prevent this and make it limited to that particular user only.
is there any way to assign same app to multiple users but create different secret keys for each user so that they cannot cross login to each other's mailbox?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use an App Registration, in that way the user uses their Azure AD credentials, not a common key.

Please check this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

Hope this helps!